# SharePoint 2010 Alert Me Not Sending Alerts when Item Deleted

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, alert

I have an alert setup on a list:

1. Send e-mail
2. Only send me alerts when: All changes
3. Send me an alert when: Anything changes
4. Send notification immediately

I received an alert when the item was added but not when the user deleted it.

Does this have to do with the user who deleted the item (which was the user who created the item)?

Why would I not receive notification that the item was deleted?

Comment: I deleted and added new alerts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recreate the alert solved the issue.